# Why mutable reference on `const` is not an error?

Tags: rust

Since the [Rust book v1.30](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/first-edition/const-and-static.html) says explicitly:

> ... constants in Rust **have no fixed address in memory**. This is because they’re effectively inlined to each place that they’re used. References to the same constant are not necessarily guaranteed to refer to the same memory address for this reason.

why the compiler allows getting a **mutable reference** on a `const` variable. It *only* says a warning/note and not an error.

```
warning: taking a mutable reference to a `const` item
 --> src/main.rs:5:22
  |
6 |     println!("{:p}", &mut VALUE);
  |                      ^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(const_item_mutation)]` on by default
  = note: each usage of a `const` item creates a new temporary
  = note: the mutable reference will refer to this temporary, not the original `const` item
```

To test this, a trivial code sample:

```
fn main() {
    const VALUE: u64 = 0;
    println!("{:p}", &VALUE);      // 0x10622ed78 // same
    println!("{:p}", &VALUE);      // 0x10622ed78
    println!("{:p}", &mut VALUE);  // 0x7ffee9a08890 // different
    println!("{:p}", &mut VALUE);  // 0x7ffee9a088e8
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20const%20VALUE%20%3A%20u64%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3Ap%7D%22%2C%20%26VALUE)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%200x10622ed78%20%2F%2F%20same%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3Ap%7D%22%2C%20%26VALUE)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%200x10622ed78%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3Ap%7D%22%2C%20%26mut%20VALUE)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%200x7ffee9a08890%20%2F%2F%20different%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3Ap%7D%22%2C%20%26mut%20VALUE)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%200x7ffee9a088e8%0A%7D)

As expected, the memory location of the `const` may change (specially when accessed using a mutable reference).

Comment: I think the warning is pretty clear about what's going on. You're not getting a mutable reference to a `const` variable, nor is the memory location of the `const` variable changing. What you are doing is creating many different temporaries, which are copied from `VALUE`, and the addresses of those temporaries are differing. The same thing would happen if you replaced `VALUE` with something like `(1+2)`, as is `println!("{:p}", &mut (1+2));`

Comment: If you consider that things like `&mut 1` are perfectly allowed (and sometimes quite useful!), there is no good reason not to allow `&mut FOO` where `FOO` is, say, 1. But it possibly turned out that most of `&mut FOO` are actually mistakes, which is why the warning was introduced.

Answer (score 6):

There are some cases where it will behave predictably. In particular, if you re-use the same reference:

```
const VALUE: u64 = 0;

fn main() {
    let v = &mut VALUE;
    add_1(v);
    add_1(v);
    assert_eq!(*v, 2);
}

fn add_1(v: &mut u64) {
    *v += 1;
}
```

I can't immediately think of a case where doing this is beneficial compared with adding a local binding first. But it can't cause memory unsafety, so it isn't a huge worry.

Given that this was not an error in Rust version 1.0, the Rust developers cannot later make it an error, because that would break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Taking a mutable reference to a constant creates a new, temporary variable. Your code is treated by the compiler as:

```
fn main() {
    const VALUE : u64 = 0;
    println!("{:p}", &VALUE);      // 0x10622ed78 // same
    println!("{:p}", &VALUE);      // 0x10622ed78
    let mut tmp1 = VALUE;
    println!("{:p}", &mut tmp1);  // 0x7ffee9a08890 // different
    let mut tmp2 = VALUE;
    println!("{:p}", &mut tmp2);  // 0x7ffee9a088e8
}
```

[Try in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=094d80acfd09f9880bbf08ccd0171a7a)

This seems like a weird way to do things, there are legitimate use cases for this behaviour when constants are [function pointers](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55721#issuecomment-643452554) or [have interior mutability](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/55721#issuecomment-643454340).